# How do I push textarea content into an array

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have a textarea that users can write in. Is it possible to push that into an array? When I console.log it I get "[object HTMLTextAreaElement]" -- is this something that can be done?

```
<textarea id="sermon" cols="100" rows="20">
Write here...
</textarea>

</div> <button id="newContent"><a href='#' onclick='downloadCSV({ filename: "card-data.csv" });'>Download your text to a CSV.</a></button>


var myArray = [];
myArray.push(sermon);
console.log(myArray.join());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with toString() function, like this :

```
Write here...
</textarea>

</div> <button id="newContent"><a href='#' onclick='downloadCSV({ filename: "card-data.csv" });'>Download your text to a CSV.</a></button>


var myArray = [];
myArray.push(sermon.toString());
console.log(myArray.join());
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML should be something like this:

```
<textarea id="sermon" cols="100" rows="20">

</textarea>

<button onclick="pushData()">Add to Array</button>
```

Javascript should be like this:

```
function pushData(){
   var text= document.getElementById("sermon").value;

    var array = [];

    array.push(text); 

    console.log(array.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find convenient not to call the javascript inline, but bind some action to the click event.

Html

```
<textarea id="sermon" cols="100" rows="20">
Write here...
</textarea>

<button id="newContent">Download your text to a CSV.</button>
```

Javascript

```
// wait for your page to be loaded
window.onload = function() {
  // declare your empty variables
  var myArray = [];
  var sermon;

  // find the button element
  var button = document.getElementById('newContent');

  // attach some code to execute on click event
  button.onclick = function() {
    // put a call to your download function here

    // get the new value of the text area
    sermon = document.getElementById('sermon').value;

    myArray.push(sermon);
    console.log(myArray.join());
}  
};
```

Comment: Oh and thanks for commenting it out. That's super helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help!